# nodejs не срабатывает клиентский js при использовании роутинга

Tags: javascript, node.js

Я сделал на странице ссылку на путь "/collection/all", и сделал обработчик запроса на путь "/collection/:user". Он перенаправляет на нужную мне хтмл страницу. Но на этой странице не срабатывает js, хотя файл отмечен как загруженный. Код:

```
app.get('/collection/:user', (request, response) => {

console.log(request.params.user) 

fs.readFile('public/collection.html', (error, html) => {
    if (error) {
        response.write(error);
    } else {
        response.writeHeader(200, {
            "Content-Type": "text/html"
        });
        response.write(html);
    }

});
});
```

Результат его работы - загружается страница, загружаются стили, загружается файл js, но скрипт внутри $(document).ready не срабатывает. Подскажите где я ошибся

Answer (score 1):

Добавил после response.write(html) вызов response.end() и проблема исчезла